# How can I .filter() through a .filter()? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to dynamically compare a `searchTag` field against an array `student.tags` , for every student which themselves all live in another array called `students`

So something like below

```
students = [
  0: {
    name: "Cheddar",
    ...,
    tags: ["gravy","steak"]
  },

  ...,

  40: {
    name: "Stacy",
    ...,
    tags: ["gravy","grade"]
  },

]
```

I'm failing bad with a filter inside a filter, and struggling returning the students who have that tag in their tag array

I can do

```
students.filter((student) => {
            if ((student.tags.includes(searchTag))) {
              return student;
            } return '';
          })
```

but this returns only on exact match and I need to find students dynamically, i.e. typing 'gra' returns both student 0 and 40, but 'grad' returns only 40

Comment: by the way, your code can be `return student.tags.includes(searchTag)` since that returns true or false, which is what you should be returning anyway in a filter callback

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: expected output is a new array of filtered students who have tags which dynamically match the search input. then I map through them and make cards. probably using the wrong word 'dynamically' but the only I found returns them if the tag exactly matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#:%7E:text=prototype.-,some(),true%3B%20otherwise%20it%20returns%20false.) to filter the array

```js
const students = [
  {
    name: "Cheddar",
    tags: ["gravy", "steak"],
  },
  {
    name: "Stacy",
    tags: ["gravy", "grade"],
  },
];

let search = "gra";

const result = students.filter(({ tags }) => tags.some((tag) => tag.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you for helping me I wasn't aware of .some() this is my working solution ```
.filter((student) => {
            if (student.tags.some((tag) => tag.toLowerCase().includes(searchTag.toLowerCase()))) {
              return student;
            } return '';
          })
```